# Can't load pretrained model from local directory

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

I finetuned a huggingface model on google colab, saved it with trainer.save_model('./results/best_model') and downloaded the files in results/best_models (config.json, pytorch_model.bin, training_args.bin)from google colab and saved it in a local directory.

Now I am trying to load the model into a jupyter notebook with

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments
import torch

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

path = 'models/yu'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path, local_files_only=True)
```

The path (models/yu) leads to a directory which contains the files from above (config.json, pytorch_model.bin, training_args.bin), it is relative to the location of my .ipynb file. Yet when I try to load it I get the following error:

`OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'models/yu'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'models/yu' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a XLMRobertaTokenizerFast tokenizer.`

What 'relevant files' could be missing? How do I load a pretrained model? Or should I have been saving the model in google colab differently in the first place?

What is also weird, is that the command produces the output

`

```
vocab_file sentencepiece.bpe.model
tokenizer_file tokenizer.json
added_tokens_file added_tokens.json
special_tokens_map_file special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config_file tokenizer_config.json
```

`
which is the same as when I (successfully) load a pretrained model which I downloaded from the huggingface hub (and saved it locally).

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Could you answer a few questions. 1. Are you on Windows or Unix-based (mac, linux)? 2. Could you describe your directory structure, in particular, where is your jupyter notebook, how did you start it (i.e. what is the active folder of the notebook), and where is the data relative to that.

Comment: Also, it probably makes sense for you to try and run the python script above outside of jupyter notebooks, just to make sure everything works. E.g. by running `python3 load_tokenizer.py`

Comment: I am running my code on a linux machine, but I think I found my mistake.. I tried to load the model with AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(...), but I was trying to fetch a model not a tokenizer. So when I tried to fetch it with AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(...) everything worked out fine:) Is the tokenizer somehow affected by my finetuning? or can I use the tokenizer from the "raw" model for my finetuned model as well? Thanks!!:)

Comment: It could be I am not sure. Depends on whether you added any vocabulary and fine-tuned the tokenizer as well... (perhaps you can try saving a default model and tokenizer using your method and then try loading it in).

Comment: Also, perhaps you can update your question with the answer and added details.